# How to get the size of a Hugging Face pretrained model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I keep getting a `CUDA out of memory` error when trying to fine-tune a Hugging Face pretrained XML Roberta model. So, the first thing I want to find out is the size of the pretrained model.

```
model = XLMRobertaForCausalLM.from_pretrained('xlm-roberta-base', config=config)
device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")

model.to(device)
```

I have tried to get the size of the model with

```
sys.getsizeof(model)
```

and, unsurprisingly, I get an incorrect result.  I get 56 as a result, which is the size of the python object.

But then, I tried `model. element_size()`, and I get the error

```
ModuleAttributeError: 'XLMRobertaForCausalLM' object has no attribute 'element_size'
```

I have searched in the Hugging Face documentation, but I have not found how to do it. Does anyone here know how to do it?

Comment: Usually when people talk about the "size" of a model, they talk about the number of learnable parameters. What what you wrote, are you looking for the size in bytes?

Answer (score 3):

Size is a little ambiguous here so here's both the answers for

#### 1. Size (No. of parameters) of a model.

Use the `.num_parameters()` function, e.g.

```
from transformers import MarianMTModel
model = MarianMTModel.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-de")

model.num_parameters()
```

[out]:

```
74410496
```

#### 2. Size (in GPU RAM) of a model.

First install this:

```
pip install -U nvidia-ml-py3
```

Then in code:

```
from pynvml import *
from transformers import MarianMTModel

def print_gpu_utilization():
    nvmlInit()
    handle = nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(0)
    info = nvmlDeviceGetMemoryInfo(handle)
    print(f"GPU memory occupied: {info.used//1024**2} MB.")

model = MarianMTModel.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-de")
model.to('cuda')

print_gpu_utilization()
```

[out]:

```
GPU memory occupied: 884 MB.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you facing `CUDA out of memory` errors, the problem is mostly not the model, rather than the training data. You can reduce the `batch_size` (number of training examples used in parallel), so your gpu only need to handle a few examples each iteration and not a ton of.

However, to your question:

I would recommend you [objsize](https://pypi.org/project/objsize/). It is a library that calculates the "real" size (also known as "deep" size). So a straightforward solution would be:

```py
import objsize
objsize.get_deep_size(model)
```

However, the documentation says:

> Excluding non-exclusive objects. That is, objects that are also referenced from somewhere else in the program. This is true for calculating the object's deep size and for traversing its descendants.

This shouldn't be a problem, but if it still gets a too small size for your model you can use [Pympler](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/), another Library that calculates the "deep" size via recursion.

Another approach would be implementing a `get_deep_size()` function by yourself, e.g. from [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128151040/https://goshippo.com/blog/measure-real-size-any-python-object/):

```py
import sys

def get_size(obj, seen=None):
    """Recursively finds size of objects"""
    size = sys.getsizeof(obj)
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()
    obj_id = id(obj)
    if obj_id in seen:
        return 0
    # Important mark as seen *before* entering recursion to gracefully handle
    # self-referential objects
    seen.add(obj_id)
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        size += sum([get_size(v, seen) for v in obj.values()])
        size += sum([get_size(k, seen) for k in obj.keys()])
    elif hasattr(obj, '__dict__'):
        size += get_size(obj.__dict__, seen)
    elif hasattr(obj, '__iter__') and not isinstance(obj, (str, bytes, bytearray)):
        size += sum([get_size(i, seen) for i in obj])
    return size
```

Comment: The very first thing I did was precisely to reduce the batch size, and still I kept getting the error. But, then I finally figured I had a bug in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Size of the pretrained weights can be found on the models website under files by checking e.g. `pytorch_model.bin`. For Bert this gives ~440MB https://huggingface.co/bert-base-uncased/tree/main

Note that the model that ends up on the GPU may be smaller or larger than this.